# Static linking with MinGW-64

Tags: mingw-w64

I'm trying to use the 64-bit MinGW from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/ but when I compile a program with it, the resulting executable fails when a DLL isn't available.

How do I get this compiler to do static linking with the standard library?

Or is there another distribution of 64-bit MinGW that I should be using instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The g++ switch is supposed to be

```
    -static
```

See
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html.

```
    -static
        On systems that support dynamic linking, this prevents linking with
    the shared libraries. On other systems, this option has no effect.
```

You should post the command line, that you use in order to compile/link, in order to get more help if this does not work for you.

Comment: if you're just linking .o files for reuse, and get an error that `main` is missing, you may also need to add `-nostartfiles`

Comment: On MinGW64, will it have the effect of `/MT` in MSVC?