# Distributing a c++ project without MINGW adn dlls

Tags: c++

I have a c++ project in vs code and I want to make it into an exe that does not require any other additional tools to be used like MINGW etc. I want to distribute it and make people not have need anything extra.

Comment: [Static linking with MinGW-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234012/static-linking-with-mingw-64) may help. What you're looking for is static linking.

Comment: add the needed dll's into the install next to the exe

Comment: How do I make an install

Comment: @RetiredNinja would you be able to help me with this linking, i'm in a rush to upload ther project for game game jam that ends in less than 3 hours.